# Pass values from a multidimensional array to object

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am creating a calendar to view shifts in calendar.I will be getting data`s from backend as array of values 
the array will be

```
 var shift = [morning shift,10:00,15:00,10/10/2018,15/10/2018],[[noon shift,10:00,15:00,10/09/2018,15/09/2018]]
```

which denotes [shift name,shift start time,shift end time,shift start date, shift end date]

I have to pass this value in an object as

```
     var repeatingEvents = [{
        title:"morning shift",
        start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
        end: '15:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

        ranges: [{
            start:new Date(10/10/2018),
            end: new Date(15/10/2018),
        }],

    },
   {
        title:"morning shift",
        start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
        end: '15:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

        ranges: [{
            start:new Date(10/09/2018),
            end: new Date(15/09/2018),
        }],

    }],

    }];
```

here i am having a multidimensional object.

for

```
apiData=[morningShift,10/09/2018,15/09/2018]
```

i have mapped the values and its working good

```
events : apiData.map(([start,end,title])=>({
                start: new Date(start),
                end: new Date(end+'T00:00:00-07:00'),
                title,
                className: 'bg-primary'})
              ),
```

How to do this for multidimentional object.I am a beginner in js and could anyone help me with this ?Thanks in advance

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a multi-dimensional anything, it's flat arrays. 
If you know the object properties from the object you can just get them directly. Otherwise iterate over the object.

Comment: What "multidimensional object" are you talking about? If you're talking about the array of arrays, as in the second element of the `shift` variable, you just need to iterate over that, perhaps recursively. BTW, '15:00' would be 3pm, not 6pm.

Comment: I am talking about the ranges there. I am fetching values within a single dimension array and I passed values successfully for the rest of the properties. I am stuck for the ranges

Comment: "ranges" is just an array. So create an array, and then add one (or more) object into the array.